# passing a tables html content to next gsp page

Tags: jquery, html, grails, groovy

I need to pass an entire html table content and trying to pass it as a param to the next gsp page in the ajax call

```
jQuery.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          data:{'table_cart': $("#table_cart").html()},
          url: '/gra/ar_request/nextpage',
          beforeSend: function() {
                   jQuery('#templateDiv').html('show spinner')
                },
          success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#templateDiv').html(data);},
          error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});
    return false;
```

when I try to retrieve the value in the next page I am getting all kinds of errors like "XML not formed properly, expecting img tag., ; missing ..etc"

I am just trying to do following to read the value on next page

```
var table_content = ${table_cart}
```

giving single quotes around the value gives error. Ineed to know how to pass the html content of a table to another gsp, is there a better way?

Details of the error on nextpage.gsp
missing ; before statement
http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js
Line 29

```
I am doing 
<script>
    var tbcont = ${rolecart}
</script>
```

I printed out the content on console from the action and it has the right content. i.e. all tags inside the table,  do i need to encode the html content? 
exact display of the content from the console is:

```
<thead>
                <tr>

                  <th scope="col" style="width: 40%">
                    <span class="column-sort">
                      <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
                      <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
                    </span>
                  Role
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col" style="width: 55%">
                    <span class="column-sort">
                      <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
                      <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
                    </span>
                 Description
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

              <tr class="odd">

                    <td style="width: 40%;"><span style="color: black;">unix_server_read</span></td>
                    <td style="width: 55%;"><span style="color: black;">Role with UNIX based entitlements having read access</span
></td>
                </tr><tr style="color:black"></tr><tr style="color:black"> <td colspan="1">End Date: <input style="width:70px" nam
e="ar_enddate" value="" id="ar_enddate" type="text"><img src="images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png" height="16" width="16"></td><
/tr><tr style="height:8px"></tr><tr class="even">

                    <td style="width: 40%;"><span style="color: black;">unix_server_write</span></td>
                    <td style="width: 55%;"><span style="color: black;">Role with UNIX based entitlements having write access</spa
n></td>
                </tr><tr style="color:black"></tr><tr style="color:black"> <td colspan="1">End Date: <input style="width:70px" nam
e="ar_enddate" value="" id="ar_enddate" type="text"><img src="images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png" height="16" width="16"></td><
/tr><tr style="height:8px"></tr></tbody>
```

Comment: Where are you getting those errors? Please paste complete error messages, with stacktraces, and the body of `nextpage` controller action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not pass html back to the server. Instead, extract the relevant parameters (using `<g:form>`) and rerender the content of the file in your AJAX call.

You can achieve this with grails by extracting the content of your `table` into [grails-template file](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.3%20Views%20and%20Templates). This way you can render the content of the table in your AJAX call.

In your main gsp file, your table will look like:

```
<table>
     <g:render template="yourTableContent" model="${[..]}" />    
</table>
```

With a `_yourTableContent.gsp` file located at the same location as your gsp is located in.

In your action called from the client you can then call:

```
def nextpage = {
    [..]
    render(template:"yourTemplateContent", model: [...])
}
```

Comment: in other words, do I need to transfer my table to a template gsp and render it on main.gsp and next.gsp, how do I handle the model or the content, not totally clear

Comment: all fields which I need should be inside the <g:form> tag?

Comment: i am not sure which kind of input elements you have.. for time being just do not use model at all. you can use it to pass some information around (like entered username or entered filter in your case).

Comment: Here's some back ground so that you can help me customize/tweak the approach you have suggested, All table values here are just text labels no input fields. This table is a 'shopping-cart' table, its values are populated at run-time using jquery from other tables, I need to know how do I get this table to the next page onclick of a 'confirm' button (either directly or by putting it in template gsp and including it in the next page?) or do I just put all items in the session/database and retrieve it next page?

Comment: Just put your table into Template file. Sounds that you so Not Need the Model Part.